# Find the second term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am posting this question here only because I find it so elegant. I found it on the French forum les-mathematiques.net, where somebody posted it, and it comes from the oral entrance exam of Ecole Polytechnique in 1987.

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a nondecreasing sequence satisfying, for all integers $n\geq 2$, $(n-1)a_n=na_{n-2}$ and $a_0=2$. Find $a_1$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h6521p22728 for a different $a_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Define a sequence by the initial values $\,a_0=2\,$ and
$\,a_1=x\,$ with
$$ (n-1)a_n = n\,a_{n-2}\quad \text{ for } \quad 
n\geq 2. \tag{1}$$
Also, suppose that $\,x\,$ is such that
$$ \,a_n\ge a_{n-1}\quad  \text { for } \quad 
n\geq 1. \tag{2}$$
We want to find the unique value of $\,x.$

For the even values of $\,n\,$ the sequence begins
$$ 2,\,4,\,16/3,\,32/5,\,256/35,\,512/63,\,\dots 
\tag{3}$$
with powers of $2$ in the numerator. In fact, for even $\,n\,$
$$ 2^n/a_n ={n-1\choose n/2}\sim 2^n/\sqrt{\pi n/2}
\tag{4}$$
using induction and Stirling's formula.
A similar result hold for odd $\,n.\,$ Since we are
given that the sequence is non-decreasing we must have
the inequalities
$$ x\ge 2,\,x\le 4,\,x\ge 8/3,\,
  x\le 32/9,\,x\ge 128/45,\,\dots . \tag{5}$$
The upper and lower bounds converge to a common limit
$\,x=\pi.$